# Scroll to Section with Menuactive Class

Tags: jquery, css

This is a nice bit of code that I use on numerous websites, that a friend helped clean up and get working exactly as needed for. Let's just say he has been out of reach for a while now, and I am having a TON of trouble trying to tweak one part of it to work slightly differently.

```
this.checkActiveSection = function(){
    var fromTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var sections = [];
    jQuery('nav ul li a').removeClass('menuactive') ;
    jQuery('.anchor').each(function(){
        var sectionTopOffset = jQuery(this).offset().top;
        var nextSectionTopOffset = jQuery(this).next().offset().top;
        if(sectionTopOffset <= fromTop){
            sections.push(jQuery(this).data('id'));
        }else if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
            sections.push(jQuery(this).data('id'));
        }
    });
    jQuery('nav ul li a, .logo a').removeClass("menuactive");
    jQuery('nav ul li a[data-id="'+sections[sections.length - 1]+'"]').addClass('menuactive');
};
this.scrollEasing = function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(this.checkActiveSection);
    jQuery('nav ul li a, .logo a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var idSectionGoto = jQuery(this).closest('a').data('id');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery('body[data-id="'+idSectionGoto+'"],.anchor[data-id="'+idSectionGoto+'"]').offset().top+1
        }, 1500, function(){
            _this.checkActiveSection();
        });
    }) ;
}
```

It is a scroll-to section function, that adds and removes a "menuactive" class to the navigation buttons. The issue I was having originally was that on certain browsers and screen resolutions, the scroll-to would be off by 1px, and you wouldn't see the correct navigation button active. Using offset().top+1 seems to have been easily resolved the issue - though I have ONE gripe with it... The +1 offset when scrolling back to the top (body anchor) drives me insane. I have tried numerous ways to tell it only to apply the +1 only to the ".anchor" class and not the "body", but it seems to break the entire scroll-to function with any method I tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The only workaround I have is using "body {margin:-1px 0 0;}" but that seems a bit silly.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) ?

Comment: Yes - not my cup of tea. Thanks though.